# UPDATE command with NULL

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, t-sql, ado.net

I am trying to update a column in my database with the date selected from a control on my ASP.NET web page. I need to ensure that the code is correct because nothing is updating in the column.

Code:

```
Command = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Parking SET ParkingStartDate = @StartDate1 WHERE Parking_ID = @radio)", myConn)

Command.Parameters.Add("@StartDate1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = StartDate.SelectedDate
Command.Parameters.Add("@radio", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = radio
Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
myConn.Close()
```

my question is if the column is already NULL, is it correct to use the update statement?

Regards.

Comment: I would always specify a *length* on any `SqlDbType.VarChar` parameters - but other than that, I think this looks ok

Comment: Answer your question, yes, it is correct to use the update statement. And your code look's fine, maybe you need to debug "radio" to watch if it had the right Parking_ID you want to update.

Comment: Checked and still not inserting the date

Comment: Put a `Try Catch` around `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()` and see if there is an exception being thrown. Being able to debug your own programs is essential.

Answer (score 1):

If `ParkingStartDate` is already null then this update statement should be fine.  If `Parking_ID` and `@radio` are both null this will probably not behave as you would expect.

In that case you would probably want to use IS NULL.